# Disassembling helloworld in sections

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, arm

I was refered by a member of community to analyse the below to understand systemcall issued in ARM architecture. I have a doubt that how to get program in this structure. I already tried gdb disas command, but sections are not visible. Pls help.

```
.data 

HelloWorldString:
      .ascii "Hello World\n"

.text 

.globl _start 

_start:
      # Load all the arguments for write () 

      mov r7, #4
      mov r0, #1
      ldr r1,=HelloWorldString
      mov r2, #12
      svc #0

      # Need to exit the program 

      mov r7, #1
      mov r0, #0
      svc #0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GNU toolchain, you can try objdump utility.
It would be something like:

```
arm-xxx-objdump -d your-binar-or-object-file
```

Comment: Actually i wanted for arm only, so thanks. So i should cross-compile my program and then issue the above mentioned command. right?

Comment: Yes. But if you have source, you can also tell gcc to save assembly file rather than object file, like Prototype Stark explained. Or tell it to save both, using command line like arm-xxx-gcc source.c -c -Wa,-aln=assembly-filename.s -o object-filename.o.

Comment: srry but can u clarify - arm-xxx-gcc source.c -c "-Wa,-aln?"

Comment: @shingaridavesh dbrank0's command works well, if you don't have the source code. If you have the source code, gcc -S filename.c is WAY shorter. Both commands work for "ARM".

Comment: You should replace arm-xxx-gcc with the name of your gcc based compiler. Try reading about it here: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html.

Answer (score 2):

```
gcc -S filename.c -o filename.S
```

Comment: Sure, you're right. If he has source, this is definitely better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command and you must be able to read the object dump much better.

your-tool-chain-objdump -d -S a.out > dump.txt

Here is a sample C code and corresponding object dump using arc-gcc.

```
int f2()
{
   int f2_var1 = 10;
   int f2_var2 = 20;
   return f2_var1+f2_var2;
}
void f1()
{
   int f1_var1 = 0;
   f1_var1 = f2();
}
int main(void)
{
   f1();
   return 0;
}
```

And the command I used is 
 arc-linux-uclibc-objdump -d -S a.out > dump.txt

dump.txt is as follows. (File is a bit big. But can't help)

```
a.out:     file format elf32-littlearc

Disassembly of section .init:

00010240 <_init-0x4>:
   10240:   00 00 00 00                            

00010244 <_init>:
   10244:   f1 c0                       push_s     blink
   10246:   e0 78                       nop_s      
   10248:   c6 08 00 00                 bl         1030c <frame_dummy>

   1024c:   7a 09 00 00                 bl         103c4 <__do_global_ctors_aux>

   10250:   d1 c0                       pop_s      blink
   10252:   e0 7e                       j_s [blink] 
Disassembly of section .plt:

00010254 <.plt>:
   10254:   00 16 0b 70 01 00 d0 24     ld         r11,[0x000124d0]
   1025c:   00 16 0a 70 01 00 d4 24     ld         r10,[0x000124d4]
   10264:   20 20 80 02                 j          [r10]
   10268:   cc 24 01 00                 cmp.z      r4,r0
   1026c:   30 27 8c 7f 00 00 6c 22     ld         r12,[pcl,0x226c]
   10274:   20 7c                       j_s.d      [r12]
   10276:   ef 74                       mov_s      r12,pcl
Disassembly of section .text:

00010278 <__start>:
   10278:   4a 23 00 30                 mov        fp,0
   1027c:   00 c1                       ld_s       r1,[sp,0]
   1027e:   b8 70                       mov_s      r5,r0
   10280:   81 c2                       add_s      r2,sp,4
   10282:   cf 70 01 00 a4 03           mov_s      r0,0x000103a4
   10288:   cf 73 01 00 44 02           mov_s      r3,0x00010244
   1028e:   0a 24 80 0f 01 00 0c 04     mov        r4,0x0001040c
   10296:   84 24 3f 3e                 and        sp,sp,-8
   1029a:   0a 26 00 07                 mov        r6,sp
   1029e:   d2 0f cf ff                 bl         1026c <_init+0x28>

   102a2:   07 00 00 00                 b          102a6 <_exit_halt>


000102a6 <_exit_halt>:
   102a6:   e9 20 60 00                 flag       1
   102aa:   4a 26 00 70                 nop        
   102ae:   4a 26 00 70                 nop        
   102b2:   4a 26 00 70                 nop        
   102b6:   f3 07 cf ff                 b          102a6 <_exit_halt>

   102ba:   4a 26 00 70                 nop        
    ...

000102c0 <__do_global_dtors_aux>:
   102c0:   f1 c0                       push_s     blink
   102c2:   fc 1c c8 b6                 st.a       fp,[sp,-4]
   102c6:   0a 23 00 37                 mov        fp,sp
   102ca:   00 16 82 70 01 00 dc 24     ldb        r2,[0x000124dc]
   102d2:   0b ea                       breq_s     r2,0,102e6 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x26>

   102d4:   29 00 00 00                 b          102fc <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x3c>

   102d8:   44 6a                       add_s      r2,r2,4
   102da:   00 1e 80 70 01 00 1c 24     st         r2,[0x0001241c]
   102e2:   22 20 c0 00                 jl         [r3]
   102e6:   00 16 02 70 01 00 1c 24     ld         r2,[0x0001241c]
   102ee:   60 82                       ld_s       r3,[r2,0]
   102f0:   f4 eb                       brne_s     r3,0,102d8 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x18>

   102f2:   01 d8                       mov_s      r0,1
   102f4:   00 1e 02 70 01 00 dc 24     stb        r0,[0x000124dc]
   102fc:   04 14 1b 34                 ld.ab      fp,[sp,4]
   10300:   00 14 1f 32                 ld.a       blink,[sp,0]
   10304:   e0 7f                       j_s.d [blink] 
   10306:   40 24 1c 31                 add        sp,sp,4
   1030a:   e0 78                       nop_s      

0001030c <frame_dummy>:
   1030c:   f8 1c c8 b6                 st.a       fp,[sp,-8]
   10310:   0a 23 00 37                 mov        fp,sp
   10314:   00 16 02 70 01 00 c8 24     ld         r2,[0x000124c8]
   1031c:   4b 7a                       tst_s      r2,r2
   1031e:   20 00 01 00                 bz         1033c <frame_dummy+0x30>

   10322:   cf 72 00 00 00 00           mov_s      r2,0
   10328:   4b 7a                       tst_s      r2,r2
   1032a:   14 00 01 00                 bz         1033c <frame_dummy+0x30>

   1032e:   cf 70 01 00 c8 24           mov_s      r0,0x000124c8
   10334:   04 14 1b 34                 ld.ab      fp,[sp,4]
   10338:   a1 c0                       add_s      sp,sp,4
   1033a:   00 7a                       j_s        [r2]
   1033c:   04 14 1b 34                 ld.ab      fp,[sp,4]
   10340:   e0 7f                       j_s.d [blink] 
   10342:   40 24 1c 31                 add        sp,sp,4
   10346:   e0 78                       nop_s      

00010348 <f2>:
   10348:   f8 1c c8 b6                 st.a       fp,[sp,-8]
   1034c:   0a 23 00 37                 mov        fp,sp
   10350:   a2 c1                       sub_s      sp,sp,8
   10352:   0a d8                       mov_s      r0,10
   10354:   f8 1b 00 b0                 st         r0,[fp,-8]
   10358:   14 d8                       mov_s      r0,20
   1035a:   fc 1b 00 b0                 st         r0,[fp,-4]
   1035e:   f8 13 03 b0                 ld         r3,[fp,-8]
   10362:   fc 13 02 b0                 ld         r2,[fp,-4]
   10366:   5a 63                       add_s      r2,r3,r2
   10368:   48 70                       mov_s      r0,r2
   1036a:   a2 c0                       add_s      sp,sp,8
   1036c:   04 14 1b 34                 ld.ab      fp,[sp,4]
   10370:   e0 7f                       j_s.d [blink] 
   10372:   40 24 1c 31                 add        sp,sp,4
   10376:   e0 78                       nop_s      

00010378 <f1>:
   10378:   f1 c0                       push_s     blink
   1037a:   fc 1c c8 b6                 st.a       fp,[sp,-4]
   1037e:   0a 23 00 37                 mov        fp,sp
   10382:   a2 c1                       sub_s      sp,sp,8
   10384:   00 d8                       mov_s      r0,0
   10386:   fc 1b 00 b0                 st         r0,[fp,-4]
   1038a:   c2 0f cf ff                 bl         10348 <f2>

   1038e:   fc 1b 00 b0                 st         r0,[fp,-4]
   10392:   a2 c0                       add_s      sp,sp,8
   10394:   04 14 1b 34                 ld.ab      fp,[sp,4]
   10398:   00 14 1f 32                 ld.a       blink,[sp,0]
   1039c:   e0 7f                       j_s.d [blink] 
   1039e:   40 24 1c 31                 add        sp,sp,4
   103a2:   e0 78                       nop_s      

000103a4 <main>:
   103a4:   f1 c0                       push_s     blink
   103a6:   fc 1c c8 b6                 st.a       fp,[sp,-4]
   103aa:   0a 23 00 37                 mov        fp,sp
   103ae:   ce 0f cf ff                 bl         10378 <f1>

   103b2:   00 d8                       mov_s      r0,0
   103b4:   04 14 1b 34                 ld.ab      fp,[sp,4]
   103b8:   00 14 1f 32                 ld.a       blink,[sp,0]
   103bc:   e0 7f                       j_s.d [blink] 
   103be:   40 24 1c 31                 add        sp,sp,4
   103c2:   e0 78                       nop_s      

000103c4 <__do_global_ctors_aux>:
   103c4:   f1 c0                       push_s     blink
   103c6:   f8 1c 48 b3                 st.a       r13,[sp,-8]
   103ca:   fc 1c c8 b6                 st.a       fp,[sp,-4]
   103ce:   0a 23 00 37                 mov        fp,sp
   103d2:   00 16 02 70 01 00 b8 24     ld         r2,[0x000124b8]
   103da:   cf 75 01 00 b8 24           mov_s      r13,0x000124b8
   103e0:   19 0a 80 0f ff ff ff ff     breq       r2,-1,103f8 <__do_global_ctors_aux+0x34>

   103e8:   22 20 80 00                 jl         [r2]
   103ec:   fc 15 02 92                 ld.a       r2,[r13,-4]
   103f0:   f9 0a 81 8f ff ff ff ff     brne       r2,-1,103e8 <__do_global_ctors_aux+0x24>

   103f8:   04 14 1b 34                 ld.ab      fp,[sp,4]
   103fc:   02 14 1f 36                 ld.as      blink,[sp,2]
   10400:   00 c5                       ld_s       r13,[sp,0]
   10402:   e0 7f                       j_s.d [blink] 
   10404:   40 24 1c 33                 add        sp,sp,12
Disassembly of section .fini:

00010408 <_fini-0x4>:
   10408:   00 00 00 00                            

0001040c <_fini>:
   1040c:   f1 c0                       push_s     blink
   1040e:   e0 78                       nop_s      
   10410:   b2 0e cf ff                 bl         102c0 <__do_global_dtors_aux>

   10414:   d1 c0                       pop_s      blink
   10416:   e0 7e                       j_s [blink]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: To get dump to a reasonable size I use "-O2" to compile the code, don't include a 'main', and don't use "-d" when I dump.